# How to add a Text View underneath aChartEngine graph

Tags: java, android, xml, achartengine

I am new to android development and achartengine.

I've managed to get the the XML almost represent what I need but I'm having a little trouble with adjusting the sizes.

My understanding of XML is pretty bad, but what I've got so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/chart"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" />

<TextView
android:gravity="center"
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Test Text"
android:textColor="#000000" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Turns out I didn't have enough reputation to post images, so I have included a link to a visual description [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bfW7.jpg). Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="hello world"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was attempting to try to organise the layout so that graphically it looked somewhat like what I wanted in the eclipse visual editor. Implementing weights me trying to get the layouts proportionally correct (I have no idea what I'm doing). I will implement your suggestions and get back. Thank you ever so much Uriel, really appreciate your help.

Comment: I deleted the second linear layout and it no longer runs. I have edited my answer to show the updated XML.

Comment: So what is the problem now? The size of the text? If yes you can change it - if you remove the textAppearance line

Comment: It now shows an entirely black screen without the graph or text, I'll remove the text appearance line and see what happens. Screenshot: http://imgur.com/PdMT44J

Comment: You need to make the textView height to be wrap content

Comment: A number underneath with the most recent value, such as in link this: http://i.imgur.com/WxPUBlB.png

Comment: So add in the text the text you need

Comment: Copying your XML exactly into my layouts file produces this image: http://imgur.com/2LelHft

I am sorry I'm so useless, you're an absolute star for helping me.

Comment: http://imgur.com/FeBX6BC The text is creeping up. Is there a way of changing the vertical margin on the text so that it is right at the top of the text view.

Comment: Uriel you're an absolute hero. Thank you so much for your help. I set a negative top margin android:layout_marginTop="-50dp" and it worked out fine. I can't upvote yet because I don't have enough reputation but I'll make sure I do when I can. Thank you again.

Comment: I'm not sure the making the android:layout_marginTop="-50dp" work on all devices. Try and see if that is working on other devices

Comment: Ty. I'll have a check.